# python exe file does not run even pyinstaller success to build

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm building a simple script of python 3.5.2 which imports pyrebase (firebase library), tkinter and openpyxl

script standalone from pycharm or cmd works perfectly.

I'm trying to generate an exe for it, I have tried to use many combinations python3.4 - python3.6, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx_Freeze and nothing worked for me.

The last thing I'm trying now it pyinstaller - python 3.5.2
now I'm usig pyinstaller to exe gui https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe

build complete successfully, when I try to run from cmd: python file.exe I get error of:

```
   SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file output\EMAInnerSpeechMain.exe on line 1
```

while I have

```
    # coding: utf-8
```

in my code

when try to run from cmd: file.exe I get the following error:

```
    File "site-packages\Crypto\Util\_raw_api.py", line 168, in load_pycryptodome_raw_lib 
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Hash._SHA256'
```

I have tried everything I find in the interent to build an exe from my script but I'm not succeeding, please help

my code:

```
# coding: utf-8
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import datetime
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color
import pyrebase
from collections import defaultdict

config = {
    "apiKey": "****",
    "authDomain": "****,
    "databaseURL": "****",
    "storageBucket": "****"
}

f  = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
firebaseData = f.database()
firebaseStorage = f.storage()

root = Tk()
welcomeLabel = Label(root, text="Please fill in \"path\" where you want data to be exported\n"
                            "and press export to excel button to start",     anchor=W, justify=LEFT)
welcomeLabel.grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)
pathLabelBase = "Path: "
pathLabel = Label(root, text=pathLabelBase, anchor=W, justify=LEFT)
pathLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

statusLabel = Label(root, text="", anchor=W, justify=LEFT)
statusLabel.grid(row=3, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)


def browsefunc():
    dirName = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if dirName != "":
        statusLabel.config(text="")
    pathLabel.config(text=pathLabelBase + dirName)


browseButton = Button(root, text="Browse", command=browsefunc)
browseButton.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W,  padx=10, pady=10)


def exportToExcel():
    dirPath = pathLabel.cget("text")
    if pathLabelBase == dirPath:
        statusLabel.config(text="Please choose directory to export excel file to.\nBy clicking on \"Browse\" button.",
                      fg="red")
    return
   ...fetching data from firebase and creating excel file

exportButton = Button(root, text="Export to excel", fg="blue",     command=exportToExcel)
exportButton.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Any is help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you find answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using auto-py-to-exe. First, open cmd, and then type:

pip install auto-py-to-exe
when installation is complete
type auto-py-to-exe in cmd

Answer (score 0):

you need to created a hook file named "hook-gclod.py" and put following code in it:-

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata
datas = copy_metadata('gcloud')
```

after doing this put it in a folder use following command to build your exe:-

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --additional-hooks-dir "path to folder with the hook file"  "path of your script"
```

[you can include  hook file from auto-py-to-exe from here:-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdcve.png)